# SimpleDateFormat: ParseException, but string date looks ok

Tags: codenameone

I have this code, with `data[][]` build from `com.codename1.io.CSVParser`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date tmpData = sdf2.parse(data[i][0]);
```

Everything works fine but when I import the CSV file I obtain this exception for each row

```
com.codename1.l10n.ParseException: Unparseable string 2010‑12‑18
```

I'm missing something?
Thank's for your help. Davide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is buried within your date separator character.

Your CSV file used this character "‑" (non-keyboard special character) while your formatter is using "-" (keyboard character and a bit longer). This seems similar and the difference is almost invisible to human eye, but they are different.

Your CSV encoding may also be the issue and it is advisable you encode your CSV in `UTF-8` standard.

## Solution:

- Copy the character separator directly from one of your CSV date strings and use that in your formatter.
- Replace the erroneous character everywhere in your CSV with the keyboard character "-" and use the same in your formatter.

Comment: Argh! It's true, invisible but different separator character, replacing with a standard keyboard "-" solved. Thank's